# Not able to use evalin or eval command in Matlab function Block(MatlabFCn) block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to evaluate a string expression in Matlab function block.

The part of code is like this:

```
coder.extrinsic('evalin')
s ='Model_On = 8';
evalin('caller','s');
```

the code is running fine but it is not assigning the varriable in the caller workspace.

The reason behind using the evalin command: the string s is variable, I can change it during simulation(I have some logic to do it).
I wanted this evalin command to assign Value(8) to variable(Model_On) in caller workspace.

Comment: What is the caller of a block? I am not sure where you expect the variable to be assigned. Using workspaces directly is typically bad practice because it kills the performance and is difficult to debug. Maybe use a output signal instead and connect it to a "To Workspace" block?

Comment: I want variable to be assigned in Matlab function block workspace(probably it is function workspace), not in base workspace.

Comment: So you are trying to manipulate mask parameters during simulation? In general that is not possible. What do you want to achieve? I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I don't think it's mask parameter, I am trying to assign different Value to variable 'Model_On' during simulation

Comment: There is no block workspace, at least I have never heard of it. There is a mask workspace but it only contains the mask parameters. Maybe instead of trying to fix your code (which is probably not possible) rephrase your question and explain what you want to achieve? Why do you think you need to assign a variable? Why can't you use a signal?

Comment: There are model workspace, function workspace apart from Mask and base workspace

Comment: There is also a [mask workspace](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/block-masks.html?refresh=true) but no block workspace, so what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to evaluate this string S mentioned above,  in Matlab function block. The part of code 
evalin('caller','s');      is not doing it.

Comment: That's your attempt to solve the problem, but it does not describe your problem. You told above that you want to assign something in the block workspace, but there is no block workspace. I assume that your evalin solution can not be fixed, I recommend to step back and describe what you want to solve. What component is intended to read the variable and for what reason do you think you have to use evalin and not a output signal?